# RespondToSelector syntax while converting from Objective-C to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Well am unable to figure out how to convert the below line to swift

```
[listener respondsToSelector:@selector(callbackme:error:)]
```

This is where i reached

```
let selector: Selector = Selector("callbackme:error:")

respondsToSelector(selecting)
```

Not sure where i need to put 'listener'?

Comment: Its just like any method invoking in Swift. <class instance>.<method name>()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it...

```
listener.respondsToSelector(selecting)
```

Comment: Of course you don't _need_ respondsToSelector most of the time; putting a question mark in the right place is usually enough.

Comment: Well listener is a protocol actually. Let me take you to the actual code (https://github.com/xyfeng/XYPieChart/blob/master/XYPieChart/XYPieChart.m#L384)